# Getting Resource ID on FullCalendar when dropping external event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using the version of the [`FullCalendar jQuery plugin`](https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar) that supports Resources.

I'm dragging in external events as per [this example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/external-dragging.html).

It all works very well, but I can't find a way to obtain the `Resource ID` that's associated with the cell (day) onto which the external event has been dropped.

I'm using the drop function below.

```
drop: function(date, allDay) { 
    // this function is called when something is dropped
    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events
    // don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" 
    // (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
```

I'd be most grateful for any help on this one please.

Comment: What do you mean by `Resource ID`? Are you looking to find the date/time of where the event was dropped?

Comment: It looks like the resource object is available on the `eventDrop` method but I think you will need to customize the plugin to make it available in `drop`.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.

It's a version of FullCalendar that allows resources to be listed down the left-hand side - see http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/

Each resource has an ID and a Name. 

Everything else is working fine, but I can't get the ID of the relevant Resource when an external event is dropped onto day.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi cOle2,

Yes, there seems to be no way in which I can obtain the id of the resource from the drop function.

Thanks

Comment: i have the exact same problem , have you managed to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I also use this fork of FullCalendar and it is possible to obtain Resource ID when you drop an event, like this:

```
drop: function(date, allDay, test3, test4, resource) {          
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
    copiedEventObject.resource = resource.id;

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
                
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
```

So, you should pass the parameter `resource` to the`drop` function and you could obtain the resource ID by calling `resource.id`.

Comment: And how can you pass the "resource" element to the drop function ? I havn't found any place where the drop function was call in this plugin.

Comment: this doesn't work. i am getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` as expected.

Comment: it doesn't work , have you hacked the plugin to be inject the resource data on the drop callback ?